# U-Boot and armhf installation

Tags: linux, arm, u-boot

I am currently trying to install ANY linux distro onto an external HD.

My goal is to boot using the external device, but my problem at the moment is that I am unable to achieve this. I try to boot the drive using U-Boot but nothing happens. I fear my problem is my lack of knowledge on armhf systems and U-Boot itself.

How can I get a bootable system onto an external hard drive (preferably using tools on a mac)? I have read some tutorials such as _link_https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/armhf/ch05s01.html.en#boot-installer-sd-image_link_ but I am not getting anywhere. I am not a linux master so can someone please give me a dumbed down response with plenty of explanations?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly standard to create a bootable USB device a quick search revealed this. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx Ubuntu is aimed at beginners like yourself so you should find plenty of support available when you search the web.

Comment: I appreciate this, but the issue I am having Is booting on an ARM processor, and booting it using u boot, not specifically a USB live disk as that is amazingly easy and I would normally just use unetbootin for that..

Comment: Have you got any more details about the architecture of the chip and the nature of the system that it resides in? I have had a look around and found this "ARM Linux is a port of the successful Linux Kernel to ARM processor based machines"  http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/docs/whatis.php

Comment: All I really have to hand is that it is an ARM v7 and that I am trying to boot the USB using U Boot... there is already a main OS on the internal HD (not my doing) but I want to boot a full OS from the usb media if plugged in... but I think u-boot is throwing me off or I am being dumb. I have been power googling for about 2 days but my knowledge is clearly not the best, so im not 100% sure what I am doing.

Comment: I would get hold of a copy of Ubuntu ARM, link here for ARMv7 netboot image http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm as long as you make sure you choose the external hard drive to install it to you should be ok (obviously don't overwrite your internal HDD). Once you have done that it should be possible to change the boot order in the BIOS of the machine to boot from the external device first, and then if it is not present it will boot from the internal device.

Comment: I have the boot order set up now (using U-Boot installed in the nand) I shall try this that you have given me... do I install this using u-net? or whats the best way to get this going / installed with no arm hardware ? (I have to build this and then boot it, even if i could get the installer started would be great)

Comment: I really dont understand what to do with the vmlinuz and initrd.gz